# Subsets with 3 consecutive terms

Tags: combinatorics

Consider the following set:
     $$\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10\}$$

I want to calculate how many subsets of length $6$ have no three consecutive terms.

My idea was to do:

length 6 have no consecutive terms = total length $6$ - length $6$ have three (or more) consecutive terms

which I thought was

$${10\choose 6} - 8 {7\choose 3}.$$

Yet this is a negative number. Any ideas?

Comment: You are counting things like $\{1,2,3,8,9,10\}$ twice.

Comment: You're overcounting in the $8{7\choose 3}$ bit. E.g., $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ is being counted $4$ times.

Comment: Have you tried the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)?

Comment: What is the "length" of a subset? The difference between the greatest and smallest element? Or what?

Comment: Wait—$\binom{10}6$ is not the number of subsets of length $6$ (whatever that means), it's the number of $6$-element subsets.

Comment: That's what I meant.

Answer (score 2):

Line up 4 sticks in a row, representing the numbers not chosen, and represent the 6 numbers chosen by dots.

The sticks create 5 gaps, so if $x_i$ is the number of dots in gap $i$,

$\hspace{.3 in}$we have $x_1+\cdots+x_5=6$ with $x_i<3$ for each $i$.

Using Inclusion-Exclusion, if $S$ is the set of all solutions and $E_i$ is the set of solutions with $x_i\ge3$,

the number of solutions is given by

$\displaystyle\big|\overline{E_1}\cap\cdots\cap\overline{E_5}\big|=\big|S\big|-\sum_{i}\big|E_i\big|+\sum_{i<j}\big|E_i\cap E_j\big|=\binom{10}{4}-\binom{5}{1}\binom{7}{4}+\binom{5}{2}\binom{4}{4}=\color{red}{45}$.

Comment: How? Where do you pull those numbers from and how can you make sure that there are 3 consecutive?

Comment: @Fermat I will try to edit my answer to add more details a little later.  The fact that $x_i<3$ for each i ensures that there are not 3 consecutive terms.

Comment: Thank you, please do try to edit it if you have time - would be really useful.

Comment: Brilliant, thank you very much. One thing - what do the straight lines in the final mean? Absolute value?

Comment: I'm using $|S|$ to denote the number of elements in the set S.

Answer (score 1):

Using the [stars and bars method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29), let stars represent the chosen numbers and bars the unchosen.

An example set-up would look like:

$|\star\star\star|\star||\star\star$

which would correspond to $(2,3,4,6,9,10)$.

The rule is that there can only be at most 2 stars between every two bar.

Meaning that, in the 5 spaces produced by the 4 bars, are numbers from 0  to 2 that add up to 6.

By using brute force:

- 0+0+2+2+2 = 6 (corresponding to $\binom52$ = 10 cases)
- 0+1+1+2+2 = 6 (corresponding to $\binom52\binom32$ = 30 cases)
- 1+1+1+1+2 = 6 (corresponding to $\binom51$ = 5 cases)

Adding up to 45 cases.

---

Edit: I tried brute-force on other examples, and found that it corresponds to [A027907](http://oeis.org/A027907), which is named:

> "Irregular triangle of trinomial coefficients T(n,k) (n >= 0, 0<=k<=2n), read by rows (n-th row is obtained by expanding (1+x+x^2)^n)."

It is converted to rows:

```
  1
  1   1   1
  1   2   3   2   1
  1   3   6   7   6   3   1
  1   4  10  16  19  16  10   4   1
  1   5  15  30  45  51  45  30  15   5   1
  1   6  21  50  90  26 141 126  90  50  21   6   1
  1   7  28  77 161 266 357 393 357 266 161  77  28   7   1
  1   8  36 112 266
```

By using the fact that it is obtained by expanding $(1+x+x^2)^n$, we can derive $T(n+1,k)=T(n,k)+T(n,k-1)+T(n,k-2)$.

Hence, completed row $8$ (counting the first row to be row $0$):

```
   1
   1    1    1
   1    2    3    2    1
   1    3    6    7    6    3    1
   1    4   10   16   19   16   10    4    1
   1    5   15   30   45   51   45   30   15    5    1
   1    6   21   50   90  126  141  126   90   50   21    6    1
   1    7   28   77  161  266  357  393  357  266  161   77   28    7    1
   1    8   36  112  266  504  784 1016 1107 1016  784  504  266  112   36    8    1
```

Also, note that our answer $45$ is on row $5$, and $45=T(5,6)$.

In general, in a set of $n$ consecutive numbers, to find the number of subsets of length $d$ containing no three consecutive terms, one simply needs to find $T(n-d+1,d)$.